# Carrying under second story deck

Tags: halacha, architecture-design, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, eruv-chatzerot

I recently spent Shabbos in an area where there was no community eiruv. The house I stayed in had a deck that one could walk out onto from the second story of the house. The deck was enclosed by walls which formed a reshus ha'yachid adjacent to the house. The deck was supported by four poles which were planted in the ground outside. A door from the first floor of the house led out to the region directly below the porch. My question is, is it permissible to walk out the first floor door and carry in the area under the porch? Specifically, can one argue that the walls of the porch above extend downward (gud achis) to create halachic walls that enclose the bottom region as well and permit me to carry in this region?

Comment: Why would you think Gud Achis (or even Pi Tikrah) wouldn't apply here?

Comment: Many of the cases of gud achis that I've seen respect to creating a reshus ha'yachid (S"A 355, gemara Shabbos 101b) involve extending mechitzos to a body of water and it seems there are some kulos that are used when water is involved (ex. mechitza teluyah is matir). I was previously unaware of this and have come to realize that using gud achis to extend mechitzos and create a reshus ha'yachid may not be so simple.

Comment: It seems there are also some limitations to pi tikrah in that it may not be able to supply all 4 walls. In this case there are no genuine walls to the structure below and we would need to use pi tikrah to create all 4.

Comment: Perhaps edit those concerns into the OP itself? (I'm not so sure that's true about Pi Tikrah, by the way. I'll have to take a look again, but I think we pasken you can use it on multiple walls.)